# XMega waveform generation with DMA and USART

Tags: microcontroller, avr, serial, xmega

I'm using an Atmel XMEGA128A4U.

I need to generate a high speed digital waveform with minimal CPU overhead, and have set up a USART to output the waveform and DMA to transfer data from a table to the USART transmit register in background.

All is working just fine, except that the first byte of the table is transmitted repeatedly by the USART. The source address counter seems to refuse to increment.

I have gone through the datasheet carefully, several times. I have tried all sorts of different initialisation orders, and added in checks for reset and busy even though other online DMA examples seem not to include them. I can get DMA working correctly with both pointers incrementing in a RAM-copy test.  I have checked the errata for the micro and there's nothing mentioned about any silicon bugs.

Can anyone spot what I may have missed?

```
/*******************************************************************************
  Function Name  : dma_out
  Description    : Initiates background memory write to port
  Input          : pointer to char source data
                 : length of block in bytes
                 : number of blocks to repeat (0 for continual transfer)
  Output         : None
  Return         : None
*******************************************************************************/
void dma_out (char *source, unsigned short len, unsigned char rep)
{
  // Enable DMA, no double buffering, round robin
  DMA.CTRL = 0x80;

  // Enable channel for configuration
  DMA.CH2.CTRLA     = 0x80;
  DMA.CH2.CTRLB     = 0x00;

  // Reset chnnel
  DMA.CH2.CTRLA     = 0xC0;
  while ((DMA.CH2.CTRLA & 0x40) != 0) // wait for reset complete
  {
  }

  // Set source and destination addresses
  DMA.CH2.SRCADDR0  = (char)((int)source);
  DMA.CH2.SRCADDR1  = (char)((int)source >> 8);
  DMA.CH2.SRCADDR2  = 0x00;
  DMA.CH2.DESTADDR0 = (char)((int)&USARTC0_DATA);
  DMA.CH2.DESTADDR1 = (char)((int)&USARTC0_DATA >> 8);
  DMA.CH2.DESTADDR2 = 0x00;

  // Wait while channel busy before setting ADDCTRL
  while ((DMA.CH2.CTRLB & 0x80) != 0)
  {
  }
  DMA.CH2.ADDRCTRL  = 0x50;  // inc source and reload each block, dest fixed

  // Set block length and repeat count
  DMA.CH2.TRFCNT    = len;
  DMA.CH2.REPCNT    = rep;
  DMA.CH2.CTRLA    |= 0x20;  // Set repeat bit only after REPCNT loaded

  DMA.CH2.TRIGSRC   = 0x4C;  // trigger on USARTC0_DRE
  DMA.CH2.CTRLA    |= 0x40;  // Trigger transfer
}
```

PS. No, I don't use ASF, or similar notation.

Comment: I don't use ASF either, but you can still write `DMA_ENABLE_bm` instead of `0x80` to make the code readable.

Comment: You also would not have made the mistake of sending CHRST (0x40) instead of TRFREQ (0x10) on the last line. Although CHRST has no effect while the channel is enabled, so the last line is a noop, just like the "Reset channel" part of the code.

Comment: Otherwise I don't see a problem (although `source` should be `const char *`). Are you sure you're not passing 1 to `len`?

Comment: @avakar: "you can still write DMA_ENABLE_bm instead of 0x80". Yes, fair comment.

Comment: @avakar: "the mistake of sending CHRST (0x40) instead of TRFREQ (0x10) on the last line". Ah yes, quite right. Thanks.

Comment: @avakar: "source should be const char *". No, source points to data held in SRAM, the DMAC can't send from code space. The one char sent does indeed change when I change the data.

Comment: @avakar: "Are you sure you're not passing 1 to len?" Lol, yes. Even setting TRFCNT and REPCNT using constants gives a continual series of one char.

Comment: Just a style remark: Using `0x80` and stuff makes the code not as easy to grasp as using `DMA_ENABLE_bm` after an `#include <avr/io.h>`.